# How to increase the max URI request in GitLab CI/CD pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am running a simple CI/CD pipeline with GitLab.
However when I send the URI request, I attach a very long token to it,
for example: ".../dir2/dir3/target/?sToken=eyJhbGciOiJSU..."
This results in error 414:

"Request URI Too Long.
The URI provided was too long for the server to process.
Try to make the request URI shorter."

I investigated the documentation for the .gitlab-ci.yml files: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/ but I did not fine any variables pointing to this limit, contrary to my expectations.

Comment: try By POST request: Convert query string to json object and sent to API request with POST.

Comment: can really tell what API you are trying to get to, but you can try to take the token out from the url to the header. (it is also depends on how did you execute the request)